# How Can I Update UI on Realtime on Android

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface

I have MainActivity and Thread Class, Just Class

MainActivty is run Thread Class, and Thread Class work with Just Class

I want to print Thread Class work result on TextView in MainActivity

Now, I can print...but it print after all work finish...

I want to output the results while the thread is working.

How can I do?

Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   .....
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.fBtn:
            fBtn.setEnabled(false);
            onFirstClick();
            break;
        case R.id.sBtn:
            onSecondClick();
            break;
    }
}
public void onFirstClick()
{
    ThreadClass tc = new ThreadClass();
    tc.run();
 }
```

and

```
public class ThreadClass extends Thread{
@Override
public void run() {
    super.run();
    WorkMethod1();
   }
    public void WorkMethod1()
   {
       WorkMethod2();
   }
   public void WorkMethod2()
   {
       WorkMethod3();
       // and Now Print work result here
   }
   public void WorkMethod3()
   {
       //.....
   }
}
```

Comment: Is your ThreadClass is inner class of MainActivity class?

Comment: You are doing print work after completion of WorkMethod3 so obvious it will print at last. You have to do print on runOnMainUIThread where you want(Here you want after every work thread completion so do print work in every thread completion)

Comment: `Thread.join` maybe resolve your problem [Read this](https://www.journaldev.com/1024/java-thread-join-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `runOnUiThread` for that. use this method instead **WorkMethod3();**

```
private void changeText(String text) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // set/change text here...
        }
    });
}
```